# How to programmatically enable bluetooth of the device when my application is opened in android 6.0

Tags: android

I want to on my bluetooth programmatically while opening the android app, the user will get any notifications to allow the bluetooth also.Because android 6 and above the gps also needed for the effective working. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

The below snippet will work for you

```
public static boolean setBluetooth(boolean enable) {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    if (enable && !isEnabled) {
        return bluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
    }
    else if(!enable && isEnabled) {
        return bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
    // No need to change bluetooth state
    return true;
}
```

to achieve this you need two permissions mentioned in your `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank you for the quick response